# apache2 mod_mono not working

Tags: apache-2.2, mono, xsp2

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 as a dedicated server. I installed mod_mono and mono-xsp2 on apache as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ModMono). Apache serves .aspx or .asmx files as files, literally. I checked and mod_mono is enabled. What could be wrong? Should I state somewhere that the mono handler should be used? xsp serves just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so this is what I had to do: add

```
MonoAutoApplication disabled
AddHandler mono .aspx .asmx
MonoApplications "/:/var/www"
```

in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: Apache fails to start with this config...